# IWD One-step Checkout on Magento 1.8

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.8, onestepcheckout

The checkout pauses on a loading screen after selecting a payment method.

The error `'Uncaught ReferenceError: checkOutLoadGiftCard is not defined`' appears on the checkout page which may have something to do with it; but i cannot find a working solution online.

The website is http://www.prinkbox.com.au/

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: My mistake, the error occurs after selecting the shipping option*

Comment: edit your question and add the error occurs after selecting the shipping option